# Bootstrap fixed width for desktop and fluid width for other devices

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a psd design with a background given to me for html5 - bootstrap development and should be responsive too.

**The psd:** 
The psd width was more than 1200px and the main container was around 900 px width and the background showed fine in the psd.

**the html**
But when I create to html and kept it responsive I found the background image was almost hidden by the main container which usually happens.

**the tweek**
then I was asked to keep it in fixed length of some 900 px when viewed on desktop and to keep it responsive (which may hide the background image - which is fine) for smaller devices. I know there is be some solution, but I was not able to find one.

**question is:**
using bootstrap how can I fix the length of a responsive design for devices larger than 900px.

Comment: Prepare custom responsive css with your sizes using http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look up [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries). I think this is exactly what you want -- it'll let you define css rules with conditions like:

```
@media (min-width 900px) {
    //css rules here
}
```

That should let you set the fixed behavior you want at widths greater than 900px, but still have more adaptive responsive behavior at smaller sizes.

Comment: Thank you for the help but I figured it out 30 mins after this post but was busy and forgot to update this. The above answer is perfect.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!